# Which are the best file-systems/mount-configuration for each folder on GNU/linux?

Tags: linux, performance, filesystems, mount

One of the good points of Linux is that is *easy* to customize the partitioning scheme of the disk and put each directory (/home, /var, etc) in different partitions and/or different disk.

Then we can use different file system/configurations for each of them for make them better.
Examples:

- **noatime** is a mount option to not write access time on the files.
- **data=writeback** is an option to lazy write metadata on new files.
- **ext3/4** has journaling that make the partition more secure in case of a crash.
- **bigger blocks** make the partition waste more space, but make it faster to read and may become more fragmented. *(not sure)*

Then: What are the best filesystem/configurations for each directory?

#### Note: given the answer of Patches, will only discuss /, /home and /var only.

/var  -> It's modified constantly, it write logs, cache, temporal, etc.
/home -> stores important files.
/     -> stores everything else (/etc and /usr should be here)

Comment: Please, there is other posts about filesystems, but there are not specific about linux, directories. ----- Please don't answer things like this filesystem is the best of all. I'm trying to learn about priorities in Linux Hierarchy and adventages of filesistem, so introduce specific adventages.

Comment: Some people put **/usr/local** and/or **/opt** on a separate partition

Answer (score 0):

You should not host `/usr` or `/etc` on seperate partitions.  `/etc` on a seperate partition simply [will not work](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/partman-target/+bug/148331) on most systems without [a lot of work](http://blog.tuxopia.net/2010/03/booting-with-etc-in-separate-partition.html).  Having a seperate `/usr` on modern Linux machines will appear to work, but break a lot of functionality, as [`systemd` author Lennart Poettering explains](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/separate-usr-is-broken):

> Most of the failures you will experience with /usr split off are graceful failures: they won't become directly visible, however certain features become unavailable due to these failures. Quite a number of programs these days hook themselves into the early boot process at various stages. A popular way to do this is for example via udev rules. The binaries called from these rules are sometimes located on /usr/bin, or link against libraries in /usr/lib, or use data files from /usr/share. If these rules fail udev will proceed with the next one, however later on applications will then not properly detect these udev devices or features of these devices. Here's a short, very in-comprehensive list of software we are aware of that currently is not able to provide the full set of functionality when /usr is split off: udev-pci-db/udev-usb-db and all rules depending on this (using the PCI/USB database in /usr/share), PulseAudio, NetworkManager, ModemManager, udisks, libatasmart, usb_modeswitch, gnome-color-manager, usbmuxd, ALSA, D-Bus, CUPS, Plymouth, the locale logic of most programs and a lot of other stuff.

`/var` and `/home` work just fine on their own partitions, and putting the latter on its own partition is highly reccomended.